# How to Publish ASP.NET WebPages with Razor (.vbhtml) to IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, razor

I've finished creating a website in Visual studio on my local machine, I have published my website to a folder on my local machine.

I have copied this folder to my windows server box in inetpub.

In IIS I have created a new website and linked to these files. Athough when I try to browse the website the page is never displayed.

How can I get my VB.NET ASP with razor website up and running from my IIS server?

Comment: Did you configure your iis correctly? installed the ASP.NET and .NET frameworks?

Comment: I didn't know this was necessary on the server due to the bin file with .dlls? Is this done through 'Web Platform Installer' then?

Comment: No using the add services tool in your windows server, the same way you added your iis

Comment: Okay, Im pretty new to this and i didnt set up the server myself. I'll do some research into this add services tool

Comment: Okay these frameworks were already installed

Comment: can you surf to `http://localhost` on your server machine?

Comment: Yes, And i turned debug on, it says 'Server Error '/' in Application' Runtime error,  Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.